# Temporal preposition (in) vs (nach)?

Tags: preposition

Do both mean 'after'? I once heard that 'nach' has a specific start point while 'in' doesn't, but I don't really understand what that really means.

I came across this example :

```
Ich plane, mein Buch bis in zwei Monaten zu beenden
```

If I was writing this sentence, I would have never included 'bis'

Secondly, whenever I read it, I immediately translate 'in' to 'within' 2 months, not after 2 months 
I am really confused regarding the difference between those prepositions ( nach vs in ) and the reason 'bis' was added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ich plane, mein Buch **in** zwei Monaten zu beenden.

*I plan to finish my book **within** two months.*

*I plan to finish my book **in** two months **from now**.*

**In** conveys *both* the time frame and the moment in time option.

> Ich plane, mein Buch **bis in** zwei Monaten zu beenden.

*I plan to finish my book **in** two months **from now**.*

This **bis in** makes it clear *zwei Monate* isn't a time frame but a moment in time counted from now.

> Ich plane, mein Buch **innerhalb** zweier Monate zu beenden.

*I plan to finish my book **within** two months.*

Using **innerhalb** *+ Genitiv* makes it clear it's a time frame.

> Ich plane, mein Buch **nach** zwei Monaten zu beenden.

*I plan to finish my book **after** two months.*

All these are valid. The difference between *in* and *nach* is very subtle. In this case, using *nach* makes the listener think you are focusing on the limit. *Two months, I don't put more effort into it.*

This is because *nach* implies thinking about what happens **after**.

> In zwei Monaten ist alles vorbei. *(thinking from the start)*
>
> Nach zwei Monaten ist alles vorbei. *(thinking from the end)*

Comment: "Two months, I don't put more effort into it. "
Sorry but I didn't get what you meant with this sentence

Comment: If you use *nach*, you make the listener think from the end. He gets the impression you have already made plans for the time **after** working on your book.

Comment: I am terribly sorry but I still don't get it, what do you mean by saying thinking from the end? and by plans after working on my book? In the sentence the speaker states that he will finish the book after 2 months, no other plans were mentioned, that will happen after he finishes the book 
I am sorry if this sounds stupid but I can't get it at all

Comment: If you have a time span as *zwei Monate*, you can either think it from now: *(bis) in zwei Monaten*, or you can think it backwards from the end of the span *nach zwei Monaten*. Bei using *(bis) in* or *nach*, you tell the pinpoint in time to stick the timeframe to.

Comment: This leads to a different perspective in the whole sentence. If you set pinpoint to now, the other end (in the future) is open and not well defined. If you set the pinpoint to the time in two months, it is well defined and creates the impression of an ending point set in stone.

Comment: Does this imply that "bis in " the speaker will start reading the book now and will try to finish it within 2 months but the endpoint isn't clear? Like he might not finish the book after 2 months, while with "nach" he is more certain that after 2 months, the book would be finished completely

Comment: *Bis in* only implies the time frame starts now. Not neccesarily the reading, but yes, as it is open-end, he may add some extra time. Future is uncertain. With *nach* however, it implies the timeframe of reading ends in two month, may he had finished the book or not.

Comment: Oh, and *ein Buch beenden* usually means *to finish **writing** a book*, not reading it. If you read a book, you would usually say *Ich plane, mit dem Buch in zwei Monaten durch zu sein.*